# What is the Golang equivalent of .Net's Marshal.Copy method?

Tags: go, memory, memory-management, marshalling

I am trying to patch a chunk of memory in Golang. I have the VirtualProtect functionality down and the memory chunk is being changed to RW, but I can't find figure out the Golang functionality for Copying into memory.

I want to emulate this from a Powershell Script:

`[System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::Copy($patch, 0, $targetedAddress, 3)`

The Golang code I currently have is below:

```
var patch = []byte {
    0x31, 0xC0, // xor rax, rax
    0xC3,        // ret
}

var oldfperms uint32
virtualProt(unsafe.Pointer(&patchAddr), unsafe.Sizeof(uintptr(2)), uint32(0x40), 
unsafe.Pointer(&oldfperms)) // Modify region for ReadWrite

var r uintptr
for _, b := range patch {
    r = (r << 8) | uintptr(b)
}

patch := unsafe.Pointer(uintptr(r)) // Attempting to copy into memory here and I'm stumped
fmt.Println(patch)

var a uint32
virtualProt(unsafe.Pointer(&patchAddr), unsafe.Sizeof(uintptr(2)), oldfperms, unsafe.Pointer(&a)) // Change region back to normal
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind. Found the reference to the Win32 WriteProcessMemory function and used that.

https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/0xrawsec/golang-win32/win32/kernel32#WriteProcessMemory

```
func WriteProcMem(currProccess uintptr, patchAddr uintptr, patch uintptr) bool {

    kern32WriteMem := syscall.NewLazyDLL("kernel32.dll").NewProc("WriteProcessMemory")
    _, _, _ = kern32WriteMem.Call(
    currProccess,
    patchAddr,
    patch)
    fmt.Println("[+] Patched Memory!")
    return true

}
```